# Nutch search always returns 0 results

Tags: search, tomcat, hadoop, nutch

I have set up nutch 1.0 on a cluster. It has been setup and has successfully crawled, I copied the crawl directory using the dfs -copyToLocal and set the value of searcher.dir in the nutch-site.xml file located in the tomcat directory to point to that directory. Still when I try to search I receive 0 results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to restart Tomcat.  If you have not since you changed the files.